# How to keep function call in parameters list easily?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

Assumes I have a function like this, it decorates parameter string:

```bsh
blue() {
  echo -e "\033[94m$@\033[39m"
}
bold() {
  echo -e "\033[1m$@\033[21m"
}
```

Now I can use it like this:

```bsh
bold "haha"
blue "haha"
```

But if I want to combine them, I have to use `$()` or backtick `` ` `` to nest them:

```bsh
bold `blue haha`
```

If I have more string decorate functions like `blink` or `add_prefix`, it's hard to combine them all:

```bsh
blink(){
  echo -e "\033[5m$@\033[25m"
}
add_prefix(){
  echo -e "\033[4mNote:\033[24m $@"
}
```

I have to nest a lot of backticks and `$()`:

```bsh
add_prefix $(blink `blue $(bold haha)`)
add_prefix $(blink $(blue $(bold haha)))
```

which is messy and hard to use.

Is there any way to keep function call in parameter list, or another recommended way to combine functions?

Comment: What happens when  the text actually happens to start with `bold` or `blue` or some other function name?

Comment: @muru You mean something like `blue bold haha`? This will treat `bold` as a string parameter, instead of a function call. So the output is a blue string "bold haha".

Comment: So what is the difference between using `blue bold haha` to print `haha` in blue and bold, and `blue bold haha` to print `bold haha` in blue? You *could* use something like `formatted_echo -blue -bold "haha"` and then parse the arguments within `formatted_echo()` but that may be more complicated than what you have right now (which actually is kind of easy to read *and* write).

Comment: @nohillside `blue bold haha` didn't print haha in blue and bold, it prints "bold haha" in blue. In `blue bold haha`, bold is not a function call but a simple  string. A backtick `\`` is needed like `blue \`bold haha\`` to treat bold as a function call.

Comment: I'm aware of that. I'm just curios what other syntax you are looking for when asking "Is there any way to keep function call in parameter list". How would this look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the output of each step in a variable:

```bsh
string="haha"
string=$(bold "$string")
string=$(blue "$string")
string=$(blink "$string")
string=$(add_prefix "$string")
```

Make sure you quote the variable at each step

---

An alternate approach is to write a control function that takes the input and the functions you want to apply

```bsh
apply() {
    local input=$1
    for func in "${@:2}"; do
        # extra credit: verify $func is a function
        input=$( "$func" "$input" )
    done
    echo "$input"
}

apply "haha" bold blue blink app_prefix
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `type` builtin bash command to find out if the chain supplied is a fonction or not:

```
$ blue () { echo -e "\033[94m$@\033[39m" }
$ type -t blue
function
$ type -t foo
$
```

So, your blue fonction could be something like

```
blue () {
    echo -ne "\033[94m"
    if [[ $(type -t "$1") == "function" ]]; then # first arg is a function name ?
        "$@"                                     # yes: exec
    else
        echo -ne "$@"                            # no: echo
    fi
}
```

This is fine for simple cases:

```
$ blue "bold haha"
```

will echo `bold haha` in blue color which is expected because arg 1 is "bold haha" and

```
$ blue bold haha
```

will echo `haha` in bold and blue which is expected too because arg 1 is the "bold" function name.

But you can't use this if you want something like

```
blue bold "i" red "want" blue "some" blink "fun"
```

You can't even have somthing correct with

```
$ blue bold blink haha
```

because you can't tell blue if "blink haha" are 1 (and should be echoed literally) or 2 (and haha must blink) arguments.

For this, i suggest another way if you absolutely want to use function: don't try to "combine" fonction. You cannot know for sure if the supplied string is a function name or a literal string.
Just write a blue, red or whatever color fonction you want and an end-color fonction, and the same for blink and bold fonction.

```
blue ()     { echo -ne "\033[94m"; } # -n avoid line break
red ()      { echo -ne "\033[31m"; }
endcolor () { echo -ne "\033[39m"; }
bold ()     { echo -ne "\033[1m" ; }
endbold ()  { echo -ne "\033[21m"; }
blink ()    { echo -ne "\033[5m" ; }
endblink () { echo -ne "\033[25m"; }
```

and now, you can do whatever you want

```
$ blue; bold; blink; echo -n "I "; endblink; red; echo -n "want "; endcolor; echo -n "some "; endbold; blue; echo "fun."; endcolor; endblink; endbold
```

which show a "I" blinking in bold blue with a red "want", white "some" and blue "fun".

For completness, I must add the simplest solution: don't use function, use parameters.

```
$ blue="\033[94m"
$ red="\033[31m"
$ endcolor="\033[39m"
$ bold="\033[1m"
$ endbold="\033[21m"
$ blink="\033[5m"
$ endblink="\033[25m"
$ echo -e "${blue}${bold}${blink}I ${endblink}${red}want ${endcolor}some ${endbold}${blue}fun.${endcolor}${endblink}${endbold}"
```

Comment: You're probably missing a `${blink}"` parameter in your last line  ;-). Not a problem, I know.

Comment: What's your bash version? I tried `type -f funcName` in bash `5.0.16(1)-release` and `4.2.46(2)-release`, it prints `bash: type: funcName: not found`. Without `-f`, it prints `funcName is a function` and function definition follows.

And in `zsh`, `type -f` prints the function definition without `funcName is a function`.

Comment: @LingSamuel Sorry, it's a typo: the correct command is type -t functionname. My blue function is correct but not the example which precedes it. I corrected. Thanks for that